# If a view is set up in IB with Auto Layout, what happens if you try to change its frame programmatically?

Tags: ios, macos, cocoa, cocoa-touch, autolayout

A project I've started helping on did not use Auto Layout before and I'm updating it to use Auto Layout and size classes.  There's a decent amount of frame manipulation code throughout the app (e.g. setting frame directly rather than changing constraint constants), and I'm wondering how this affects a view that's been set up with Auto Layout constraints.

I'm working on doing away with the frame-changing portions of code and changing it to update constraint constants where needed, but since I'm not yet 100% familiar with how every piece of the code works, it'd be helpful to have a better understanding of how auto layout and coded frame changes can affect each other so that if a view doesn't appear properly at runtime I can better determine if it's something I set up or perhaps a piece of older code somewhere that needs to be found and updated.

Comment: Usually, the change will work until the next layout when the frame is again set to the frame defined by constraints. Sometimes the layout happens immediately so the change is not actually visible.

Comment: if you are doing a lot of frame manipulation on a view which uses autolayout this can be a mess. i had once such task and most of code was doing nothing (when trying to change frame), the runtime was ignoring most of operations on frames.

Comment: @Sulthan, that makes a lot of sense when thinking back to some of the weird results I've gotten at times.  Thanks!

Comment: it usually works... if it doesn't then try to figure out what went wrong and fix it... no problem is being shown until you try something...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's very simple. You just have to understand what auto layout *is*.

Here's how it works. The constraints are just a list of instructions; they do not, of themselves, actually do anything at all. There's a system message `layoutSubviews`, which is sent at moments you do not control — so you should imagine it could be sent any time. When `layoutSubviews` *is* actually sent, the constraints are consulted and obeyed (by doing exactly what you would do — that is, the runtime sets the `frame`, or the `bounds` and `center`, of each view).

Thus, you are free to change the `frame` of a view, but be aware that if `layoutSubviews` is sent and the constraints disagree with the `frame` that you set, the view will *jump* back to where the constraints say to put it.

Comment: Perfect, thank you!  This explains some of the sketchy results I was getting back in some cases.